# Service is incorrectly selecting Pod listening on some different port

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I tried the Service definition example from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service).

So, I created below Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-simple-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

And then to test the concept, I created below Pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: service-simple-service-pod
  labels:
    app: MyApp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: service-simple-service-pod-container-1
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - containerPort: 9376
```

And I can see that a new Endpoint for this Pod is created, so all good till now, below is the output:

```
C:\Users>kubectl describe service/service-simple-service
Name:              service-simple-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=MyApp
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.98.246.70
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        9376/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.8:9376
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Then to test negative concept, I created below Pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: service-simple-service-pod-nouse
  labels:
    app: MyApp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: service-simple-service-pod-nouse-container-1
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - containerPort: 9378
```

But to my surprise this Pod was also picked:

```
C:\Users>kubectl describe service/service-simple-service
Name:              service-simple-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=MyApp
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.98.246.70
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        9376/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.10:9376,10.244.0.8:9376
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

My understanding of Service I created above was that Scheduler will look for any Pod having label as `app: MyApp` and running on port `9376`, so my expectation was that since this Pod is running on port `9378` so it will not be picked up. So, my question is that why this "service-simple-service-pod-nouse" was picked up?

If someone says that my understanding was incorrect and Service only selects Pod based on Label, then my question is that since "service-simple-service-pod-nouse" Pod is listening on port `9378` then how "service-simple-service" Service can send traffic to this Pod?

Comment: AFAIU, the `ports` array in your container definition is purely decorative. If you Service selector matches a Pod, then that Pod would be a member of the Endpoints for that Service. Regardless of that Pod actually listening on your Services targetPort.

Comment: Do you have some link where I can read more on the line of explanation you gave above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sevice will picked all the pods that are labeled as the label selector of that service. `service-simple-service` service will select all the pods that are labeled as `MyApp` because you tell in the service selector (`app: MyApp`). This is the common and expected behavior of label-selector, you can see the k8s official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-simple-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

## Update

Basically, a service get the requests and then it serves the traffic to the pods (those are labeled as the service selector), when a service take a pod then it opens a endpoint for that pod, when traffic comes to the service it sends those traffics in one of it endpoints(which is basically going to a pod). And the container port is basically the port inside the pod where the container is running.

Comment: But official docs clearly say - "which targets TCP port 9376 on any Pod with the app=MyApp label". So, in order to be selected a Pod should meet both criteria. If you say otherwise then can you explain the question I mentioned in last para of my post..

Comment: The "nouse" pod has the label, so it's selected, and the service targets port 9376 on it.  The criterion is not "has the label and a container listening on the port", only "has the label".

Comment: @DavidMaze Ok, I have two question then: (1.) then it means Service will send all the traffic to only one Pod. Is it correct? (2.) What is the point of selecting a Pod which is not listening to desired port? Wouldn't it unnecessarily have a performance hit because everytime Service receives a request, it will try to send traffic to "service-simple-service-pod-nouse" only to find that this Pod is not listening on port "9376"? I think we are missing something...

Comment: I think you can read the k8s official [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) doc, for getting clear idea. Some key points: 1. The set of Pods targeted by a Service is usually determined by a selector. 2. This specification creates a new Service object named "my-service", which targets TCP port 9376 on any Pod with the app=MyApp label. 3. As many Services need to expose more than one port, Kubernetes supports multiple port definitions on a Service object.